# UITabBarController with none selected controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ipod-touch, ipod

In the 3.0 version of the iPod application (and maybe in previous versions too) when the iPod application is launched after a sync the UITabBarController appears with no tab selected...

[iPhone iPod loading screen](http://twitpic.com/8hlpm)

Is there any way to accomplish the same behaviour? or is this just the Default.png displayed by the iPod app at startup?

Answer (score 1):

This will work when your tab bar is already loaded:
`self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = nil;`

In applicationDidFinishLaunching, you'll have to use something like this:
`[tabBarController performSelector:@selector(setViewController:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the default.png, when I launch mine the loading screen appears to be all black - and you wouldn't expect a default.png to be able to have the tab bar elements when you are allowed to re-order them as you are in the iPod app.

Perhaps if you set the UITabBarController selectedVC to nil...

Comment: I tried to set the selectedViewController to nil at applicationDidFinishedLaunching but when the view appeared the first view controller was automatically selected

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look/feel like it is done with Default.png. Looking at the [docs online (under selectedViewController)](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController), you can select a view controller that isn't shown in the tab bar but still in the viewControllers array, and may be this is how it's done in the iPod/music app. So essentially make a view controller for a tab that isn't selectable from the tab bar by the user, and select that view controller programatically.

Comment: If the selectedViewController is set to a view controller tha is not shown in the tab bar the the 'More' tab bar item is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Was able to get this working by making the selection on my tab bar controller from `applicationDidBecomeActive` with the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = splashScreenControllerThatHasNoTab;
}
```